# Minimum domino rotations - with python

Tags: python

In this exercise, we need to rotate dominos so that the numbers on one of the rows (either top or bottom) is all equal. The dominos will be given as two lists of integers, one for the top row and one for the bottom row. The rotation is done by swapping the top and bottom row of a domino. Ensure you do the most efficient rotations possible.

In the case of the image below the lists would be 2,6,2,1,2,2 and 5,2,4,2,3,2. The solution would be to rotate the second and the fourth domino, so that the top row becomes 2,2,2,1,2,2 and the bottom row becomes 2,6,4,1,3,2. The function will return the required number of rotations which would be 2 in this example If the task is impossible, the function should return -1.[image]

My attempt

```
def min_domino_rotations(top, bottom):

    counter_t = 0   # the number of times a number appears in the "top" list
    counter_b = 0   # the number of times a number appears in the "bottom" list
    num_t = 0       # the most frequent number in "top" list
    num_b = 0       # the most frequent number in "bottom" list
    counter = 0     # count the number of times we need to flip

    for i in top:        # I use a for loop to determine which number it is and how many times it appears in "top" list
        current_frequncy = top.count(i)
        if current_frequncy > counter_t:
            counter_t = current_frequncy
            num_t = top[i]

    for i in bottom:   # I use a for loop to determine which number it is and how many times it appears in "bottom" list
        current_frequncy = bottom.count(i)
        if current_frequncy > counter_b:
            counter_b = current_frequncy
            num_b = bottom[i]

    if counter_t > counter_b:   # To see whether top row or bottom row should be fliped
        for i in top:
            if top[i] != num_t: # if an element is not the most frequently appearing number defined as above, flip it with the bottom one
                top[i] = bottom[i]
                counter = counter + 1
                return counter
                if bottom[i] != num_t # if task is impossible
                    return -1
    elif counter_b > counter_t:
        for i in bottom:
            if bottom[i] != num_b:
                bottom[i] = top[i]
                counter = counter + 1
                return counter
                if top[i] != num_b
                    return -1


print(min_domino_rotations([2, 6, 2, 1, 2, 2], [5, 2, 4, 2, 3, 2]))
```

This doesn't seem to work, can someone tell me where i went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think this solution would be simpler. It's all explained in the code:

```
def min_domino_rotations(top, bottom):
  if len(top) == 1:
    return 0 # already solved

  # we want to find which value 1-6 exists on all dominos
  # (if domino has 2 equal values, count only once)
  counters = [-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  for t, b in zip(top, bottom):
    counters[t] += 1
    if t != b: 
      counters[b] += 1

  # find value, that occurs in all dominos
  try:
    target_value = counters.index(len(top)) 
  except:
    return -1 # no value occurs on all dominos

  # count rotations to turn the TOP row to the target value
  rotations_top = 0
  rotations_bottom = 0
  for t, b in zip(top, bottom):
    if t != target_value:
      rotations_top += 1
    if b != target_value:
      rotations_bottom += 1
  # maybe turning to the BOTTOM row would result in fewer rotations
  rotations = min(rotations_top, rotations_bottom)

  return rotations
  
print(min_domino_rotations([2, 6, 2, 1, 2, 2], [5, 2, 4, 2, 3, 2]))
print(min_domino_rotations([2, 6], [6, 6]))
```

Comment: Ehmmm it says that the rotating number is not correct...

Comment: @JerryCohen yeah, I found a counter example, e.g. `[2, 6], [6, 6]`. My previous code only sought 6 on top row, while in reality the bottom row maybe has fewer rotations. I changed the code in the answer

Comment: thanks! mb i got a bit impatient, didnt even read your code just copy pasted....